# Passing variable from directive to controller in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

So I have an nvd3 graph in my index.html whose height is set to {{varyingHeight}} like so (code snippet):

```
<nvd3-line-plus-bar-chart data="data"
           showXAxis="true" showYAxis="true"
           tooltips="true" interactive="true"
           showLegend="true"
           height='{{varyingHeight}}'
           >
 </nvd3-line-plus-bar-chart>
```

Now in my directive, I have a code which identifies when the height change takes place, and what the new height is:

```
app.directive('test', function () {
 return {
 restrict: 'EA',
 scope: {},
 link: function (scope, element) {
   scope.$on('split.resize', function() {
     console.log('I got resized');
     console.log(element.height());
    });    
  }
       };
  });
```

In my controller, I now want to be able to set the new height like so:

```
$scope.$apply(function(){
   $scope.varyingHeight = h;  
})
```

I'm new to angularjs so I can't figure what the best way is to do this. I have seen answers which show how to do this the other way round, i.e from the controller to the directive but this hasn't helped me. How do I pass a `element.height()` to variable `h` from the directive to the controller? Or is my code structured wrong in the first place?

Comment: do you want to change height on the directive?

Comment: Yes, ideally because I've figured out how to watch for changes on that element in the directive. But if there is a better approach, I'm willing to learn!

Answer (score 1):

You do it by binding the `height` attribute to the value passed from the controllers scope. Here's an example: http://jsbin.com/vapipizu/1/edit

The important part is that you replace `height="{{varyingHeight}}"` with `height="varyingHeight"` and that your directive binds the `height` attribute like this:

```
scope: {
  height: '='
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer, but I'm not sure I understand. The controller is the one watching for the change in this case am I right? When I change `height="varyingHeight"`I immediately get an `Invalid value for <svg> attribute height="varyingHeight"` error and my graph isn't rendered at all.

Comment: You can have watches for the height in both the controller and the directive. The reason your getting that error is probably because `attrs.height` no longer contains the height, you need to access it on the scope instead with `$scope.height`. Maybe I didn't understand your question. Is the `nvd3` directive yours? Or do you have one controller, one `nvd3` directive that you didn't create, and another directive that you've created that will modify the height?

Comment: Yup exactly. I have my own controller, my own directive that modifies the height and of course the angularjs nvd3 directives that I haven't touched.

Comment: Looking at the code for the `nvd3-line-plus-bar-chart` directive (https://github.com/cmaurer/angularjs-nvd3-directives/blob/master/src/directives/nvd3Directives.js) it doesn't seem that it listens to changes to the `height` attribute. So you can change the value of `varyingHeight`, but the directive won't react and update the height. Your best bet is either to modify the source for the directive to add a watch for `height`, or to create a wrapper directive which recreates `nvd3-line-plus-bar-chart` when the height changes.

Comment: Oh yes! I just put in this bit of code `scope.$watch('height',function(height) {return scope.d3Call( scope.data, scope.chart );});` which worked perfectly when I used a function like this `var h = 200; setInterval(function(){$scope.$apply(function(){ h = h + 50; $scope.varyingHeight = h; })}, 10000);` in the controller. But this passing of variable height is what has me stuck. (Sorry about the awful formatting)

Comment: Ah okey, good. Then you can use my example, but ignore what I said about modifying your HTML for the `nvd3-line-plus-bar-chart` diretive. That is, in my example `my-dir` is your other directive and not the `nvd3-line-plus-bar-chart` directive. I've updated the example to show how you can watch and change the height value both in the controller and directive.

Comment: OK, thank you so much! I will try this approach and let you know if it works.

Answer (score 0):

I also faced this issue, I resolved it by passing the height as attribute to the directive

My sample directive

```
App.directive('aBc',function () {
return {
    restrict : 'AE',
    scope : {
        gridHeight : '@'
    },
    template : '<div style= "height : {{gridHeight}}px" >'
        +'<p>sdtyhdrtydrt--  {{gridHeight}} </p>'
        + '</div>'
};
```

});

pass the height through directive tag

directly you can pass the height

```
<div a-bc grid-height="200"></div>
<div a-bc grid-height="500"></div>
<div a-bc grid-height="1000"></div>
```

or you can set it from your controller

```
<div a-bc grid-height="someHeight"></div>
```

initialize someHeight in controller like

```
$scope.someHeight = 500;
```